# Union the same one column in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
ID | booking_id | branch_id | service_id | staff_id | rating
1  |    21      |    2      |      null  |   null   |   5
2  |    21      |    null   |      5     |   null   |   3
3  |    21      |    null   |      7     |   null   |   5
4  |    21      |    null   |      8     |   null   |   5
5  |    21      |    null   |    null    |    7     |   5
6  |    22      |    3      |    null    |   null   |   4
7  |    22      |    null   |      8     |   null   |   2
8  |    22      |    null   |    null    |    10    |   1
```

What i want to return is like this when the booking_id is the same

```
booking_id |branch name  |service name           | staff name |branch rating|service rating|staff rating 
    21     |LA branch    |massage, wax, therapy  |   John     |  5          |  3 , 5 ,5    | 5
    22     |Vegas Branch |   therapy               |   May    |  4          |      2       | 1
```

The service id will only union in one column same with the service rating that is in the rating.

Comment: But consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: And how do you know what the values refer to?  You should probably simplify the question to focus only one the parts that you care about -- rather than cluttering the question with unnecessary tables.

Answer (score 0):

for service_rating, instead of MAX(),  you should use group_concat()

```
 group_concat(service_id)) AS service_rating,
```